# Struts - How to escape encoded symbols within a text field

Tags: html, struts2, placeholder, html-escape-characters

I have a struts text field with some default text inside of it. The default text needs to include the trademark symbol. I would like to know how to get the symbol to display. I have tried a few different things which only output the code and not the actual symbol.

My script looks something like

```
<s:textfield value = "Add a Number\&#169;" 
          cssClass = "text-input-large" 
               rel = "someNumber" 
         maxlength = "12" />
```

Comment: I thought the hex was `&#8482;` for TM, is it not?

Comment: Please add an applicable “struts” tag to your question. This must be struts-specific, since using escapes in HTML is simple. BTW, note that ín HTML, `&#169;` denotes the copyright sign ©.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Either way the symbol doesn't show up only the hex

Answer (score 0):

Test: `&#8482;` or `&trade;`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3rXum/)

And for HTML-escaping:

```
<s:property value="name" escape="false" />
```

Comment: This does not work within struts. I have edited my post to specify that I am working with Struts tags.

Comment: I just tried escape="false" and escapeHTML="false" neither of them works.

Comment: Check this link :http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/property.html  I think you have other problem not related to this.

Comment: This is a struts textfield not a property.

Answer (score 0):

What you want has been standardized in HTML5 with the introduction of **the `placeholder` attribute**:

> Placeholder text is displayed inside the input field as long as the field is empty. When you click on (or tab to) the input field and start typing, the placeholder text disappears.

- [Check out the Browsers Compatibility](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#placeholder)

That said, Struts `<s:textfield/>` does allow Dynamic Attributes, then you can write custom attributes like the above one. **But they will be escaped too**.

Then you have two working ways to achieve the result:

1. Use `UTF-8` everywhere (you already should), and write the character directly in your tag:

   ```xml
   <s:textfield placeholder="Lorem Ipsum ©" />
   ```
2. Use the HTML format, but in a standard HTML input type text, bypassing the Struts tag:

   ```xml
   <input type="text" placeholder="Lorem Ipsum &#169;" />
   ```

<kbd>[Running Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AndreaLigios/3VMT2/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for your response however the placeholder attribute does not work. It throws an error.

Comment: I figured out why I was getting an error and got rid of it however the placeholder tag still prints the TM code rather than the symbol.

Comment: are you putting `&#169;` on a s:textfield ? Please read the question carefully. It works, there is also a running example :|

Comment: yes. The running demo is an html input field. I am using <s:textfield>

Comment: Then write the symbol as in the s:textfield example